# Which is the best way to build release apk with smaller size?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

While i am building release apk with the command

`flutter build apk --release`

it is of size  **18 mb.**

While i run the command

`flutter run --release`

it gives me apk of size **8 mb.**

Please help me with the best practice

Comment: You should follow docs flutter https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#build-an-apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to upload it to Play Store the best practice is to build app bundles,if you wanted to build apk files then try splitting your apk with this command:

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

or specify a target platform

```
 flutter build apk --target-platform  <platform>`
```

You have options like android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.

For more details, please follow flutter documentaion docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#build-an-apk